# Closing tabs with changing window.name

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I’ve done a lot of research on and off Stackoverflow and I’ve read many posts and tried many suggestions to no avail.
So I am posting a new question since all the answers that I have read haven’t led me to a solution.

**Issue**: I need to close all tabs that I’ve opened via window.open() function.

My original implementation uses LocalStorage to keep track of tabs that have been open via the parent window.
When a link is clicked (in the parent window), a new tab is open via window.open(“url”, “uniqueId”);
I store the uniqueId in an array in localstorage which in essence is my list of tabs.
To close all the windows that I opened, I loop through the localStorage array (the tablist).
I get the window uniqueId which I use to reference and close the (child) window…

```
// (localstorage)  myTabList': [“window1”,” window2”,” window3”,” window4”]
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(‘myTabList'));

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newWindowObj = window.open('', arr [i]);
if (newWindowObj != null) {
newWindowObj.close();
}}
```

This works like a charm as long as the (child) window.name doesn’t change.
Unfortunately, the names of some of the (child) tabs do change.

I have no control over the child tabs.
Think of if as if I open Google or Bing website in a child tab and the name changes.

```
Parent window (tab)
link A <a href=”#” @click=”window.open(‘http://www.google.ca’,’GOOGLE’) ”>Google</a>
link B <a href=”#” @click=”window.open(‘http://www.bing.com,’BING’)”>Bing</a>
```

I should point out that the tabs that change names load 3rd party web apps that are cross domain.

My app (parent tab web app) is a Vue 2.x project. Since the implementation described above doesn’t work as desired when a window name changes, I need a different solution.

I thought I could persist the tabs (window object)  in an array of windows using the “vuex-presistedstate”.

If I use simple objects with Strings (just for testing purposes) to store data, all works flawlessly. e.g. storing objects containing String properties in an array  *{“url”:’http;//www.google.com”, “name”: “GOOOGLE”},  {“url”:’http;//www.bing.com”, “name”: “BING”}*
But I run into issues when I try to store actual window objects.

```
var myTabList = [];

var newWinRef = window.open(“url”, “uniqueId”);
myTabList.push(newWinRef);
```

The storage of the window seems OK… based on the console output.
But it’s followed by this message.

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
-- starting at bojec with constructor 'Window'
-- propery 'widow' closes the circle
```

So this solution doesn’t works very well either.

All I am trying to do is to open a window via window.open and persist some info about the newly opened windows / tab so that I can identify the tab(s) and call window.close() to close the child tab.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!